# If $S$ is a compact surface and $R$ is a straight line, then there is some $p$ in $S$ such that the normal line intersects $R$ perpendicularly

Tags: differential-geometry, surfaces

Consider the following problem (Exercise 2.71 in *Curves and Surfaces*, 2nd Edition, by Montiel and Ros):

> Let $S$ be a surface and let $R$ be a straight line of $\mathbb{R}^3$. Prove that if $S$ is compact, then there is a point of $S$ whose normal line intersects $R$ perpendicularly.

My attempt of solution:

Let $R = \{ta + p_0 \in \mathbb{R}^3 \ ; \ t \in \mathbb{R} \}$, with $|a| = 1$, and consider 
$$
h(p) = |p-p_0|^2 - \langle p - p_0, a \rangle^2
$$
be the square of the distance between $p \in S$ and $R$. Since $h$ is continous and $S$ is compact, we know that $h$ attains an extremum and hence has a critical point. Let $p$ be the critical point. Then, for every $v \in T_pS$ we know that 
$$
(dh)_p(v) = 0 \implies \langle v, p-p_0 \rangle = \langle p - p_0, a \rangle \langle v, a \rangle. 
$$
Note that from this it follows that $a \in T_pS$. Hence $R$ is parallel to $T_pS$.

At this point I am stuck. Any hints will be the most appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: You're missing the “$,a$” after the final $p-p_0$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure how you concluded that $a\in T_pS$. Here's how I did: I noted that $h(p)$ does not depend on the choice of $p_0$, so we can after the fact choose $p_0$ to be the point on the line closest to our minimizing $p$, so that $\langle p-p_0,a\rangle =0$. Then you're done.

Comment: $a$ is in $T_pS$ because if you substitute $v$ for $a$ in the equality I wrote, you get that it is satisfied.

Comment: Oh, so obvious. Try my way to finish the problem.

Comment: Could you develop your answer, please? I can see that $h$ does not depend on $p_0$, but I fail to understand your conclusion.

Comment: If $p_0$ minimizes the distance from $p$ to the line, then the inner product I stated must hold. This says that the line through $p_0$  and $p$ is orthogonal to $R$. But your equation tells you this line is orthogonal to $T_pS$.